# update permalinks, sign out, sign in NIGHTMARE

Tags: workflow

Is there a secret workflow I don't know for developing Wordpress sites? I am constantly finding I have to either update permalinks or sign out and sign back in to see changes. Sometimes I have to do both. I am using MAMP and Coda 2 as my IDE. I'd love a list of tricks to make life better while developing for Wordpress.

Comment: When do you have to sign out and in to see changes? If you change rewrite rules then you have to refresh them - it's normal (but you can do it with code).

Comment: I have never really had a problem that resembles the one you describe. You have to update permalinks if you change them, but the login/loginout issue is puzzling. Make sure your server does not cache and maybe switch off browser caching as well.

Comment: Hmm. I always have the cache disabled in my browser. I just checked preferences for my server (MAMP) and there is a cache option but the drop down menu is just disabled and displays "--". I don't know what the problem is.